# PHP Regex Question

Tags: php, regex

I am developing an application using PHP but I am new to regular expressions, I could not find a solution to my problem. I want to replace all occurences of #word with a link, i have written a preg_match for this:

```
$text=preg_replace('~#([\p{L}|\p{N}]+)~u', '<a href="/?aranan=$1">#$1</a>', $text);
```

The problem is, this regular expression also matches the html character codes like

```
&#039;
```

and gives corrupt output. I need to exclude the words starting with &# but i do not know how to do that using regular expressions.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'~(?<!&)#([\p{L}|\p{N}]+)~u'
```

That's a negative lookbehind assertion: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php

Matches # only if not preceded by &

Comment: The vertical bar (`|`) is not necessary within the character class (`[...]`).

Answer (score 1):

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

use this online regular expression constructor. They have explanation for every flag you may want to use.. and you will see highlighted matches in example text.

and  yes use [a-zA-Z]

Comment: I need letters from other languages, that's why I am not using [a-zA-Z].

Comment: there's some mbstring regexp functions too they help to use nonlatin matches.. or stmng like this=)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a `[A-Za-z]` rule in your regular expression statement so that it only limits itself to letters and no numbers.

<strike>I will edit with an example later on.</strike>

Comment: I think he wants numbers because he uses \p{L}|\p{N} not just \p{L}

Comment: The problem is not the numbers, I also need numbers in the word.

The problem is the & sign at the beginning.

Comment: hmm yeah I just realized it by rereading your question. But at least you got an answer to your problem.